# CASE Statements [Oracle/SQL]

Tags: sql, database, oracle, case

I've created several CASE Statements in which none work, that have all different errors. I have currently spent the past few hours trying to figure them out and simply can't get them. If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong in each, it'd be great.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, to_number(MANAGER_ID, '9999'), COMMISSION_PCT,
CASE 
WHEN '"MANAGER_ID" > 0' THEN MANAGER_ID
ELSE '9999'
END AS"Review"
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID BETWEEN 80 AND 90
```

With this code, I am supposed to be Creating a new Column 'Review' with the following information entered:
If they have a manager id, then that will be shown
If they don't have a manager id, then the Commission_pct will be shown
If they don't have commission, then '9999' will be shown

[Upon writing this, I noticed I never had any commands regarding Commission_Pct, but I'm assuming that wouldn't even fix this issue anyways.]

My next issue is

```
Select NAME, START_DATE, to_char(END_DATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY'),
CASE END_DATE
       WHEN '30/Sep/2004' THEN 'End in 2 weeks' 
       ELSE SYSDATE
END AS "PROMOTIONS"
FROM f_promotional_menus
```

With this code, it's a bit weird buts heres the requirements of it.
If there is an end date, temporarily replace it with "end in two weeks." If there is no end date, replace it with today's date.

My Final Issue

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, to_number(DEPARTMENT_ID, '99999), to_number(SALARY, '9999999.99'),
CASE DEPARTMENT_ID
WHEN '10' THEN '1.25*"SALARY"'
WHEN '90' THEN '1.5*"SALARY"'
WHEN '130' THEN '1.75*"SALARY"'
ELSE SALARY
END AS "NEW_SALARY"
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Again, a new column with the requirements of-
If the department id is 10 then 1.25 * salary
If the department id is 90 then 1.5 * salary
If the department id is 130 then 1.75 * salary
Otherwise, display the old salary.

If anyone even has the vaguest ideas on where I went wrong, and has a suggestion regarding on fixing it, that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The way Stack Overflow works is: You ask one question at a time. Please, can you split your three questions into three different Stack Overflow questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is funny.  You have found several different ways to be confused.

The first:

```
CASE WHEN '"MANAGER_ID" > 0' THEN MANAGER_ID
     ELSE '9999'
 END AS "Review"
```

Well, you have single quotes where you don't want them.  In fact, you can remove all the quotes, assuming `Manager_Id` is a number:

```
CASE WHEN MANAGER_ID > 0 THEN MANAGER_ID
     ELSE 9999
 END AS Review
```

The second:

```
CASE END_DATE
       WHEN '30/Sep/2004' THEN 'End in 2 weeks' 
       ELSE SYSDATE
END AS "PROMOTIONS"
```

This is a date format issue.  I recommend the `DATE` keyword followed by `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
CASE END_DATE
       WHEN DATE '2004-09-30' THEN 'End in 2 weeks' 
       ELSE TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END AS PROMOTIONS
```

Note that the `ELSE` and the `THEN` return the same types.

The third:

```
CASE DEPARTMENT_ID
    WHEN '10' THEN '1.25*"SALARY"'
    WHEN '90' THEN '1.5*"SALARY"'
    WHEN '130' THEN '1.75*"SALARY"'
    ELSE SALARY
END AS "NEW_SALARY"
```

Is also a quoting issue.  Assuming `DEPARTMENT_ID` is a number, you can remove all quotes:

```
CASE DEPARTMENT_ID
    WHEN 10 THEN 1.25 * SALARY
    WHEN 90 THEN 1.5 * SALARY
    WHEN 130 THEN 1.75 * SALARY
    ELSE SALARY
END AS NEW_SALARY
```

If `DEPARTMENT_ID` is a string, then you should have the quotes on `WHEN` value.